# How to show kendo-datepicker as windows calander format with 60 days Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular10, kendo-datepicker

I need to show a datepicker calendar just like windows but with 60 days (30 current month 15 previous month dates and 15 future month dates) in angular and also with scrolling feature like windows

I have tried the below where i kept calendarType as classic but it is not either scrolling or showing 60days

`<kendo-datepicker calendarType="classic" [value]="value" ></kendo-datepicker>`

**Is there any way around to show 60days or to enable scrolling option to  calendarType="classic" Please help me out**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Did you try `[min]`  and  `[max]`  properties of `kendo-datepicker` ?

Comment: @JayanikaChandrapriya Thank you for responding Yes i tried this but it is showing only between the dates but i need it like in same month just like windows calendar current month should be blended with previous 15days and future 15days

Answer (score 2):

This process might be helpful for you to get some idea of how to make it. In the component after setting the properties. Get the First date of the last month (assign it to relevant variable):

```
new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() - 1, 1);
```

Similarly, Omit the First 15 days from the Last month, Get the First date of the current month and Get the Last date of the current month. Then format the dates to match the format in your Date Picker

```
this.datePipe.transform(lastMonthLastDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: The date part is ok but how do i show those in classic kendo calendar OR is there any way to set scrollable option for classic type Kendo-Calendar maybe like fast slidebar or fast navigation bar ?